# Display order of a SQL Query without order by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am writing a simple query in SQL Server:

```
Select 
    EmpId, EmpName, Sal 
from 
    Emp 
where  
    EmpId in (10,9,5,7,3,8);
```

I want to get the output in a same order which is given i.e; `10,9,5,7,3,8`

Actually whatever I'll give the result will display with given order without
order by ascending or descending.

How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: what op you getting from this query

Comment: `IN` clause does NOT provide a way to change the order of data.

Comment: How are you calling this? There could be a dynamic way to do this

Comment: @AmeyDeshpande Right now it is displaying in ascending order. Like 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Comment: @FelixPamittan can you give me an example for doing it?

Comment: @MaciejLos So how can I get the result as per my requirement. Is there any alternate way to do that?

Comment: If you *need a specific order*, then you ***MUST*** use an explicit `ORDER BY` - no way, no hack, no trick around it. Just get used to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No way to do this natively.
Try:

```
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (10,9,5,7,3,8)
ORDER BY CASE EmpId
    WHEN 10 THEN 1
    WHEN 9 THEN 2
    WHEN 5 THEN 3
    WHEN 7 THEN 4
    WHEN 3 THEN 5
    WHEN 8 THEN 6
    ELSE 7
END;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use a table variable to pass the inputs. You must insert the records into this table variable in the desired order.

```
Declare @empids table(id int identity(1,1),empid int)
insert into @empids values(10),(9),(5),(7),(3),(8)

Select e.EmpId,e.empname,e.sal from Emp e
join @empids t on  e.EmpId = t.empid 
order by t.id
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CHARINDEX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173376(v=sql.90).aspx) function in an odd way: search for the id in the comma separated list and order the result by the position.

Consider this list for example `10,9,5,7,3,8`... the substring 10 appears at 1<sup>st</sup> position while 9 appears at 4<sup>th</sup>. Just order by the substring position.

```
CREATE TABLE Emp
    (EmpId int, EmpName varchar(100), Sal int)
;

INSERT INTO Emp
    (EmpId, EmpName, Sal)
VALUES
    (1, 'John', NULL),
    (2, 'Jane', NULL),
    (3, 'Smith', NULL),
    (4, 'Doe', NULL),
    (5, 'Ben', NULL),
    (6, 'Steve', NULL),
    (7, 'Andrew', NULL),
    (8, 'Simon', NULL),
    (9, 'Jack', NULL),
    (10, 'Allen', NULL)
;

SELECT
    EmpId, EmpName, Sal
FROM
    Emp
WHERE
    EmpId in (10,9,5,7,3,8)
ORDER BY
    CHARINDEX(CONCAT(',', EmpId, ','), CONCAT(',', '10,9,5,7,3,8', ','))
;
```

Result:

```
EmpId | EmpName | Sal
------+---------+-----
10    | Allen   | NULL
9     | Jack    | NULL
5     | Ben     | NULL
7     | Andrew  | NULL
3     | Smith   | NULL
8     | Simon   | NULL
```

Comment: While this is definitely a hack, it's the kind of hack that a problem like this deserves - and one I would happily use for an ad-hock query!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this dynamically if your list is a comma-delimited-string. First, you must have a splitter function. Here is the [**DelimitedSplit8k**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) written by Jeff Moden:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](
    @pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,cteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)
,cteStart(N1) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1, L1) AS(
SELECT 
    s.N1,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1),0) - s.N1, 8000)
FROM cteStart s
)
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
```

Then, you declare the list of `empId`s as csv string and use the splitter:

```
DECLARE @empIds VARCHAR(MAX) = '10,9,5,7,3,8';

SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, e.Sal 
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@empIds, ',') s
    ON s.Item = l.EmpId
ORDER BY s.ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the exact result (without order by):

```
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (10)
union all
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (9)
union all
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (5)
union all
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (7)
union all
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (3)
union all
SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Sal
FROM Emp
WHERE EmpId IN (8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Ids` is a variable passed as input parameter to a stored procedure, you can split it using [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
--@inputIDs VARCHAR(300) => '10,9,5,7,3,8'

;WITH MyIds AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Position, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(@inputIds, CHARINDEX(',', @inputIDs)-1)) AS MyId, 
        RIGHT(@inputIds, LEN(@inputIds) - CHARINDEX(',', @inputIDs)) AS Remainder
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', @inputIDs)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Position +1  AS Position, CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Remainder, CHARINDEX(',', Remainder)-1)) AS MyId, 
        RIGHT(Remainder, LEN(Remainder) - CHARINDEX(',', Remainder)) AS Remainder
    FROM MyIds 
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', Remainder)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Position +1 AS Position, CONVERT(INT, Remainder) AS MyId, 
        NULL AS Remainder
    FROM MyIds 
    WHERE CHARINDEX(',', Remainder)=0
)
SELECT e.EmpId, e.EmpName, e.Sal
FROM Emp AS e INNER JOIN MyIds AS a ON e.EmpId = a.MyId
ORDER BY a.Position
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is probably to use a table-valued constructor as a table expression containing the ids with a sort value, then order on this value:

```
Select 
    Emp.EmpId, Emp.EmpName, Emp.Sal 
from 
        Emp
    Inner Join
        (
            Values
                (10, 1),
                (9, 2),
                (5, 3),
                (7, 4),
                (3, 5),
                (8, 6)
        )
        EmpIds (EmpId, Sort)
            On
                Emp.EmpId = EmpIds.EmpId
Order By
    EmpIds.Sort Asc
```